# PHP - How to insert data from checkbox into database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a specific problem and as a unskilled person I have no idea how to solve that. In my database I have a many-to-many relationship between ARTISTS and GENRES and the table between them (called RELATION) is created of id_artist and id_genre.
When I'm creating a new artist (php, html) - using the form, I need to insert id_artist (auto_increment) and other arrays into the table ARTISTS (there is no problem ;) ) but simultaneously I need to insert multiple id_genre from checkbox into the RALATION table. Any ideas? :)

Here is code for inserting data into the table ARTISTS

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO artist(jmeno, lokace, popis, live) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['jmeno'], $_POST['lokace'], $_POST['popis'], $_POST['live']));

header('Location: index.php');
```

And form without checkbox for genres.

```
<body>

<?php include 'navbar.php' ?>

<center><h1>New artist</h1></center>

<center><form action="" method="POST">

    <p>Artist<br/><p>
    <input type="text" name="jmeno" maxlength="30" value=""><br/><br/>


    <p>Location<br/><p>
    <input type="text" name="lokace" value="" maxlength="25" required><br/>

    <p>Description<br/><p>
    <textarea name="popis" cols=40 rows=6 maxlength="200" required></textarea><br/><br/>

    <p>Live<br/><p>
    <input type="radio" name="live" value="ano" checked> Yes<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="live" value="ne"> No<br/>

    <br/>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Save"> or <a href="artists.php">Cancel</a><p>

    </form></center>
        <?php include 'footer.php'?>

 </body>
```

Comment: Sorry, are you saying you're having trouble saving data from a checkbox value, or is there another issue here.

Comment: I can't save data from checkbox value too and the another issue is that I have no idea how to insert data from one form into two tables.

Comment: @kojenec Your form doesn't have any checkboxes, only radio options, and you're using the right method to save radio options. To save checkboxes you want to use `isset($_POST['checkbox'])` to see if it's been set. To add same data to multiple tables just prepare and execute another query and reuse the `$_POST` variables.

Comment: Well I prepared the checkboxes and I would like to know, how to insert id_artist into the table RELATION.

Comment: Ignore last comment, now deleted. Are you saying you want to get the ID from the previous row insert to use in your next insert? If so, you can use `$db->lastInsertId();`

Comment: I'll try that... thank you for the help ;)